# C# loop loops the first statement three times before moving to the second statement

Tags: c#, loops, console-application, do-while

I have wrote this do-while loop in a console app in C#:

```
do 
{
    ThisHelp.ShowMenu();
    userChoice = (char) Console.Read();
    ThisHelp.Helpon(userChoice);
}while(ThisHelp.IsValid(userChoice) == false);
```

The method `ThisHelp.ShowMenu()` has just a bunch of Write + WriteLine methods, which are asking the user to type a number from 1 to 8.
The method `ThisHelp.Helpon()` has a switch that depending on the user input passed, shows a different piece of text.
The method `ThisHelp.IsValid` just checks that the user input is a number from 1 to 8.

Here's the problem: After the user writes a number and presses ENTER, the first statement of the loop executes 3 times before the second statement executes at least once. Why is this happening?

edit: Here is the code of the `ThisHelp.IsValid` method, as requested:

```
public bool IsValid(char ch)
{
   if (ch < '1' | ch > 8 & ch != 'q') return false;
   else return true;
}
```

Comment: You should use `int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())` instead of `(char) Console.Read()`

Comment: Dont you have to validate the input before executing the `ThisHelp.Helpon(userChoice);` method?

Comment: @DCruz22 In case the user inputs an invalid character, the `ThisHelpon(userChoice);` method won't print out anything, and the execution will jump out of the loop, as intented. I could do it in a different way, but the exercise required me to use the do-while loop, so I did that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `Console.Read()` returns *every character* the user enters. So if he enters `8` and *then presses ENTER* you get three characters:

- `8`
- `\r` (carriage return) and
- `\n` (new line)

You may rather use this:

```
char userChoice = Console.ReadLine().Trim()[0];
```

But be sure to add some error handling for empty inputs.

Answer (score 6):

`Console.Read()` generally only returns when the user has pressed return - at which point the carriage return and line feed will *also* be returned by subsequent calls to `Console.Read()`. You can validate that by logging (or examining in the debugger) the value of `userChoice` on each iteration.

It would probably be simpler to just call `Console.ReadLine()` which will consume the whole line, then convert that value to an integer.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. But I accepted the other answer, because it worked too, but with less keystrokes. For example I'd have to change the parameters decleration of the methods from type char to int too...

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting the second two lines of the loop into one. Try something like this:

```
ThisHelp.Helpon(Char.Parse(Console.Readline()));
```